# Pandas: How to flatten lists of dicts within a list of dicts into dataframe, throwing error if any dict in nested list is missing any specified keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My ultimate goal is to flatten a key within a list of dicts into a dataframe. The key's value is also a list of dicts, and that list could be empty for any given record in the top-level list. I'm trying to do this quickly, so trying to use vectorized operations in pandas, including `json_normalize` (which I assume is better than a loop).

In the resulting dataframe, I want to keep some top-level columns while flattening all of the keys in the list of nested dicts. I *also* want the operation to fail if there is any dict in any nested list that does not have all of the keys I specify. But, I do *not* want the operation to fail if the key exists but is `None`. (This is why I can't just check `NaN` after the normalization -- `None` is converted to `NaN` for float types in `json_normalize`, since it does not provide a `dtype` arg, so I wouldn't know whether it was `NaN` because the key didn't exist, or because it did exist but was `None`).

For example, I tried doing something like this:

```
data = [
  {
    'id': 1, 
    'topfield1': "1-1",
    'topfield2': "1-2",
    'topfield3': "1-3",
    'topfield4': "1-4",
    'payments': [
      {'id': 1, 'amt': 2.0, 'not_required': 'something'},
      {'id': 2, 'amt': 4.0}
    ]
  },
  {
    'id': 2, 
    'topfield1': "2-1",
    'topfield2': "2-2",
    'topfield3': "2-3",
    'topfield4': "2-4",
    'payments': [
      {'id': 1}
    ]
  },
  {
    'id': 3, 
    'topfield1': "3-1",
    'topfield2': "3-2",
    'topfield3': "3-3",
    'topfield4': "3-4",
    'payments': []
  }
]

# now flatten into one row for each item in each record's 'payments' key, keeping top-level 'id', 'topfield1', 'topfield4' and raising error if payments.id or payments.amt does not exist in a payment

#ideally, it would work like this:

# i want this to raise an error since data[1]['payments'][0] does not have key 'amt'. apparently that's not how json_normalize works -- it just throws a TypeError because apparently meta columns can't be from the record_path
pandas.io.json.json_normalize(data, record_path='payments', meta=['id', 'topfield4', 'topfield1', ['payments', 'id'], ['payments', 'amt']]) 
'''expected output
KeyError: 'payments.amt' or something like that
'''
'''actual output
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
'''

data[1]['payments'][0]['amt'] = None
# now every 'payment' has 'id' and 'amt' keys so should succeed. but this still throws TypeError.
pandas.io.json.json_normalize(data, record_path='payments', meta=['id', 'topfield4', 'topfield1', ['payments', 'id'], ['payments', 'amt']]) 
'''expected output
id  topfield4  topfield1  payments.id  payments.amt  payments.not_required
1      1-4     1-1             1            2.0            something
1      1-4     1-1             2            4.0              NaN
2      2-4     2-1             1            NaN              NaN
'''
'''actual output
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
'''
```

But this doesn't work. Whenever I use fields from the `payments` objects -- i.e. keys of the objects in the `record_path` list -- as fields in the `meta` arg, I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

It also seems like `json_normalize` isn't smart enough to actually follow the paths you give it in the `meta` arg, since: (though I guess I could just rename the relevant top-level columns to avoid)

```
# data as from above
pandas.io.json.json_normalize(data, record_path='payments', meta=['id'])
# fails with ValueError: Conflicting metadata name id, need distinguishing prefix`
# (shouldn't it know `id` is top-level since it's not a nested path?)
```

Is there a vectorized/fast way to accomplish what I want to do?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT 1: There could be many top level fields and I want a subset of them in the final dataframe.
EDIT 2: Added more fields to make a minimum reproduceable example.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, we can flatten your dict with a simple comprehension and read the outer id as the keys to use as the index. we then concat whilst reading the values as a dataframe.

```
df = pd.concat(
    {d["id"]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d["payments"]) for d in data}, sort=False, axis=0
).reset_index(0).rename(columns={"id": "payments.id", "level_0": "id"})
```

---

```
print(df)

   id  payments.id  amt not_required
0   1          1.0  2.0    something
1   1          2.0  4.0          NaN
0   2          1.0  NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Will it work if I want 1) more than one -- but not all -- top level fields (there could be many top level fields -- edited the question to reflect this) and 2) to throw an error if a payment doesn't have 'amt' key (or any other key I specify)? I will check myself later. Also not sure if a comprehension is vectorized, was trying to stay with vectorized operations, but maybe that's not possible.

Comment: @ryanwc if you post a [mcve] that matches your dataframe then I can have a look

Comment: thanks, sure, I edited the above dict list to provide what I think is a minimal reproducible example. the bit about needing to throw an error (or some other way to tell) if any of the specified keys in the dicts-to-flatten are missing is already in there, tried to make it more clear